# Installing Chrome with Playwright on Google Cloud Run for Python

Tags: google-cloud-run, playwright-python

I'm getting a `Executable doesn't exist at /root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1019/chromium-1019/chrome-linux/chrome` error on Google Cloud Run whenever I try to install Playwright for Python, and I can't find a workaround for it, already tried to download and install a Chrome version but I don't know who to set the path to it.

Was anyone able to achieve this?